# Set prototype attribute using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem using Class with setter using ajax. Here is the condition.

```
var MyClass = Class.create();
MyClass.prototype = {
    myAttr:0,
    setMyAttr: function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'data.php',
            success:function(data) {
                //set myAttr here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to set `myAttr` inside the success function, how to do this? Thanks. :D

Comment: `MyClass.prototype.myAttr = ...`, perhaps?

Comment: Note that you'll have timing issues. Until the ajax completes, `myAttr` will be 0.

Comment: yes, i was looking for `MyClass.prototype.myAttr = ...`. Thx for your help. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said what `Class.create` is (there is none in JavaScript itself), but I don't think it matters much for the question.

I assume you want to set `myAttr` on the **instance**, not the prototype (but see below if I'm wrong). The simplest way is to take advantage of the fact that your `success` callback is already a closure over the context of the call to `setMyAttr`, so you set a variable to be `this` (since `this` will be different in the `success` callback) and use that:

```
var MyClass = Class.create();
MyClass.prototype = {
    myAttr:0,
    setMyAttr: function(){
        var self = this;            // <== Set the variable
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'data.php',
            success:function(data) {
                self.myAttr = data; // <== Use it
            }
        });
    }
};
```

More on closures: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

But if I'm wrong and you do actually want to update the prototype instead:

```
var MyClass = Class.create();
MyClass.prototype = {
    myAttr:0,
    setMyAttr: function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'data.php',
            success:function(data) {
                MyClass.prototype.myAttr = data;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

*(Note the `;` at the end of the assignment to the prototype. I strongly advocate not relying on the horror that is automatic semicolon insertion.)*

Comment: yes, I'm using prototype and it works! Thanks for your help :D

Comment: lol, thx for ur advice. I'll always put `;` next time. hahaha.

Comment: @DarwinGautalius: Glad that helped! FWIW, if you're using Prototype 1.6 or higher (and if not, why not?), you shouldn't be replacing the `prototype` property of the function returned by `Class.create`. You should be passing an object into [`Class.create`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/create/). (Doesn't change the answer, but just FWIW...)

Comment: I use the latest version of prototype, downloaded today. But idk how to do that? This day is my first time using prototype :p. i found the code replacing prototype somewhere in an old tutorial. I'll be very glad to be explained. :D

Comment: @DarwinGautalius: You pass the properties you want added to the prototype into the `Class.create` function: http://pastie.org/5483768 I hate to mention this, but if you're just starting using Prototype, you might want to consider whether to do that. The project (which I used to be involved with, years ago) is very, very slow moving and not keeping up with other JavaScript libraries. For DOM manipulation, I'd recommend jQuery, and for class creation and such, I'd recommend my own [`Lineage`](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) toolkit.

Comment: just noticed u gave a link, i'll just read there. thx for ur great advices. :D

Comment: @DarwinGautalius: Happy to help. Best,

Comment: your toolkit? that's sound interesting! actually i don't really want to use prototype, I've been very confused today because of many conflicts with other libraries and your toolkit seems to be the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
        success:function(data) {
            //set myAttr here
            MyClass.prototype.myAttr = data;
        }
```